# Are biometrics shared between GCC?

Tags: overstaying, uae, kuwait, biometric-passports, gcc

Are only the biometrics of people who are blacklisted or convicted in any GCC country shared or are all biometrics of each and everyone who visits any GCC country shared throughout ?

A friend of mine has been to Kuwait but not convicted or blacklisted or overstayed, but he now needs to go to Dubai with a different named passport for some family reason. Not for any crime. Will he still be detected even though he is not a criminal? are his details shared?

Comment: @pnuts not sure it is implemented in all GCC countries, I know that Kuwait and Saudi do share these.. not sure the rest implemented that or not yet.

Comment: Please specify why your friend would worry about such a thing, otherwise the question is unclear.